# Collection Where LIKE Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I know collection doesn't support where LIKE but how can I achieve this.

My data is:
[image]

```
collect($products)->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $productName . '%');
```

Laravel doesn't support where like in the collection. I'm thinking to use

```
collect($products)->filter( function () use ($productName) {    
    return preg_match(pattern, subject);
});
```

But I don't know how to do it. TY

Answer (score 82, accepted):

On a collection you can use the `filter($callback_function)` method to select items in the collection. Pass in a callback function that returns `true` for every item that should be returned.

In your case you can use the [`stristr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) function to emulate a `LIKE` operator, like this:

```
collect($products)->filter(function ($item) use ($productName) {
    // replace stristr with your choice of matching function
    return false !== stristr($item->name, $productName);
});
```

Just replace `stristr` with `preg_match` or what ever you need to match strings.

This will return the collection in its original structure minus the non matching items.

Comment: Instead of `stristr()` I recommend using `stripos()`, consumes less memory.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the @Stephen Ostermiller's answer
By Updating vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Traits/EnumeratesValues.php

It is possible to overriding the EnumeratesValues trait by creating a new App/Collection.php file.
Then use this collection type instead.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection as EloquentCollection;

class Collection extends EloquentCollection
{
    /**
     * Get an operator checker callback.
     *
     * @param  callable|string  $key
     * @param  string|null  $operator
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return \Closure
     */
    protected function operatorForWhere($key, $operator = null, $value = null)
    {
        if ($this->useAsCallable($key)) {
            return $key;
        }

        if (func_num_args() === 1) {
            $value = true;

            $operator = '=';
        }

        if (func_num_args() === 2) {
            $value = $operator;

            $operator = '=';
        }

        return function ($item) use ($key, $operator, $value) {
            $retrieved = data_get($item, $key);

            $strings = array_filter([$retrieved, $value], function ($value) {
                return is_string($value) || (is_object($value) && method_exists($value, '__toString'));
            });

            if (count($strings) < 2 && count(array_filter([$retrieved, $value], 'is_object')) == 1) {
                return in_array($operator, ['!=', '<>', '!==']);
            }

            switch ($operator) {
                default:
                case '=':
                case '==':  return $retrieved == $value;
                case '!=':
                case '<>':  return $retrieved != $value;
                case '<':   return $retrieved < $value;
                case '>':   return $retrieved > $value;
                case '<=':  return $retrieved <= $value;
                case '>=':  return $retrieved >= $value;
                case '===': return $retrieved === $value;
                case '!==': return $retrieved !== $value;
                case '<=>': return $retrieved <=> $value;
                case 'like': return str_contains($retrieved, $value);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Copy paste the function operatorForWhere and add the case 'like', like suggested.

Answer (score -3):

**For Laravel Collections->where, the best one line code; less memory usage is this**:

This solution works for all your future `Collection->where('', 'like', '')` scenarios... and it supports emptyStr lookups while other solutions don't.

1. Edit this file ... `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Collections/Traits/EnumeratesValues.php`
2. Add just one line code of `case 'like': return str_contains($retrieved, $value);` to the Switch statement of the `operatorForWhere` function in the file above to look like this:

   ```
            switch ($operator) {
                default:
                case '=':
                case '==':  return $retrieved == $value;
                case '!=':
                case '<>':  return $retrieved != $value;
                case '<':   return $retrieved < $value;
                case '>':   return $retrieved > $value;
                case '<=':  return $retrieved <= $value;
                case '>=':  return $retrieved >= $value;
                case '===': return $retrieved === $value;
                case '!==': return $retrieved !== $value;
                case 'like': return str_contains($retrieved, $value);
            }
   ```
3. Use it like this `$members->Where('name', 'like', trim($this->searchText))`
   Don't add `'%'`. You don't need that.

Just save your files and retry. All set!

You don't have to always invoke the `Collection->filter`... reserve `Collection->filter` for something more involved.

Comment: Editing a file in the venfor folder is not a good solution as any update with composer will remove your change. Use this only on your local dev environment for testing only.

Answer (score -7):

Another option is to add the `WHERE LIKE` clause when you're querying the database (fetching the collection in the first place) instead of getting all items and then filtering down.

For example :

```
$products = Product::where('name', 'like', '%match%')->get();
```

Since you're still dealing with the database and SQL (and not yet a collection), that works.

Comment: He is working with a collection. The worst case would be to iterate through everything and match result.