# Laravel collection filter for 'A%' just like we do with where like 'A%'

Tags: php, laravel, filtering, laravel-collection

I want to filter a bunch of names that start with a **character** followed by wildcard *****

**Query**
I can achieve that with a query e.g. `return $q->where('name', 'like', $name . '%');`

Since I have the modal::class cached, I don't want to repeat it rather use **filter()** or **something else** that can help me get the expected results.

**Collection Filter()**

```
return $collection->filter(function ($q) use ($name) {
    return false !== stripos($q['name'], $name); // this returns all the names that contains $name character
});
```

What I want to achieve is to filter() names that starts with a specific character and then '%' -- `$name . '%'` e.g. `'A%'`

Below are the couple of SO link I went through
[Collection Where LIKE Laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103711/collection-where-like-laravel-5-4)
[Laravel 5.5 Collection where like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47413022/laravel-5-5-collection-where-like)

Comment: use the `filter()` method.

Comment: @IGP I agree. But I want to know how I can mimic `'A%'` using filter() and stripos()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`Str::startsWith`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-starts-with) helper.

> ```
> use Illuminate\Support\Str;
>
> $result = Str::startsWith('This is my name', 'This');
>
> // true
> ```

Applying to your code, it should be

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return $collection->filter(function ($q) use ($name) {
    return Str::startsWith($q['name'], $name);
});
```

For laravel versions prior to 5.7, use the [`starts_with`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-starts-with) helper instead.

> ```
> $result = starts_with('This is my name', 'This');
>
> // true
> ```

Answer (score 0):

consider this collection:

```php
$certs = collect([[
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Master'
], [
    'id' => 2,
    'name' => 'Doctor'
]]);
```

here's an example of `Collection` way of filtering records that works exactly the same as `where like` sql query statement feature.

```php
$collectionWhereLike = function ($collection, $key, $term) {
    $filtered = $collection->filter(fn ($item) => Str::contains($item[$key], $term));
    $reIndexed = array_values($filtered->toArray());
    return collect($reIndexed);
};
```

usage

```php
$filtered = $collectionWhereLike($certs, 'name', $term);
```

examples

```php
// when
$term = '';
```

```json
// ouputs
"Illuminate\Support\Collection":[
    {"id":1,"name":"Master"},
    {"id":2,"name":"Doctor"}
]
```

```php
// when
$term = 'to';
```

```json
// ouputs
"Illuminate\Support\Collection":[
    {"id":2,"name":"Doctor"}
]
```