# How to search Array Collect where city_name LIKE $city?

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

### How to search collect array Laravel where city_name value is Like $city?

here my array

[image: array picture]

My code right now :

```
$city = "Aceh Barat";
$result = collect($object)->where('city_name',$city);
return response()->json($result);
// THE OUTPUT IS ALL DATA FROM ARRAY WHICH THE city_name VALUE IS "Aceh Barat"
```

> what i need is when $city = "Ace", they will return all data from
> array which the city_name contain words "Ace"

can you help me? your help is very needed :) thankyou

Comment: Does this answer your question? 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103711/collection-where-like-laravel-5-4

Comment: @HarunYilmaz unfortunately its not sir :(

Comment: @KamleshPaul it returns undefined $item->city_name

Comment: @sta it returns error undefined "city_name" in $item->city_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need where like on collection:

thank to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44103784/10573560) you can do it like:

```
$city = "Aceh Barat";    
 $value=   collect($object)->filter(function ($item) use ($city) {
            return false !== stristr($item['city_name'], $item);
        });
```

Comment: thanks for comment, but i got this error  =  "message": "Trying to get property 'city_name' of non-object",

Comment: try it like: return false !== stristr($item['city_name'], $item);